# Initializing XAML user control

Tags: c#, xaml

I am very new to C# and I'm trying to initialize a XAML user control window when I start my scripting program. It's just a basic window with textboxes, and comboboxes. The XAML code and C# code are listed below respectively. Since I have Express, I am unable to use the MVVM light toolkit. I am also using VS2010 because that is what the original code for this program was. The VMS.TPS.Common.Model.API and Types are dll's used for this particular program. Keep in mind that the C# code has to have this basic skeleton, otherwise it won't work. The 'public void Execute' portion is where I need to code.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="426" d:DesignWidth="736">
<Grid Margin="10" Width="702" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using VMS.TPS.Common.Model.API;
using VMS.TPS.Common.Model.Types;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WpfApplication1;

namespace VMS.TPS
{
    public class Script
    {
        public Script()
        {
        }


        public void Execute(ScriptContext context, System.Windows.Window window)
        {

        }                 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be very simple if i understood it right :

```
UserControl1 testUsrCtrl = new UserControl1();
```

And then set required properties.
Make sure you have all the references in place.

Comment: Thanks @Ujjwal. That works really well in the VB workspace but when I use it in the program it gives me the error:

**The type or namespace 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'(are you missing an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace 'WpfApplication1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Since I can only include a .cs file extension in my program to run a script, can I still run a xaml app in that environment? It looks like it has been referenced.

Comment: @LitteringAnd, could you please elaborate more about "scripting"? Which scripting are you using? May be you should update your question.